# C++ Newton Raphson method is slower than bisection?

Tags: c++, methods, iteration, bisection

My task is to find the root of a function with both the Newton Raphson and the bisection method within an error margin of 10E-7.
The point of all that is, that we learn that the Newton Raphson method is faster and more effective.
Now for some reason I come to the opposite result. Although I am aware that the initial guess of the root in both methods strongly affects the number of necessary iterations. But I entered a similar guess in both algorithms and my fellow students dont get the result I do.

Bisection method:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;


//Declaring the given function
double func1(double x) {

    return 0.00000000027 * (x - 10000000) - 0.16460351745 * (-1 + ((1000000000) / (x))) * 1 / (sqrt(x));

}

int main() {
    std::fixed;


    //Initial guess: root ist at 10 to the 7.
    double x1 = 10000000;
    double x2 = 1000000000;
    double eps = 0.0000001;
    int i = 0;
    double x0[100000];
    x0[0] =0;


    //Exception handler
    if (func1(x1) * func1(x2) > 0) {
        cout << "Root is not inside the bracket.";
        goto end;
    }
    goto start;


    //Bisection Algorithm 
    while (abs(x0[i] - x0[i-1]) >= eps) {

    start:

        i = i + 1;
        x0[i] = 0.5 * (x1 + x2);


        if (func1(x1) * func1(x0[i]) < 0) {

            x2 = x0[i];
        }
        else {
            x1 = x0[i];
        }





    }

    cout << endl << "Bisection Method: " << fixed << setprecision(10) << x0[i] << endl << "Iterations: " << i << endl << endl << endl << endl << endl;

    end:
    return 0;
}
}
```

Newton Raphson:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

// Declaring the function and its derivative
 double func1(double x) {

  return 0.00000000027 * (x - 10000000) - 0.16460351745 * (-1 + ((1000000000) / (x))) * 1 / (sqrt(x));

}

double funcderiv1(double x) {

     return 0.00000000027+((0.1646035174)/(2*x*x*sqrt(x)))*(30000000-x);

}


int main()
{
    std::fixed;
    double eps = 1;
    double x_start = 10000000;
    double c;

    int i = 0;

    while (eps >= 0.0000001) {


        c = x_start - ((func1(x_start)) / (funcderiv1(x_start)));
        eps = abs(func1(x_start) / funcderiv1(x_start));
        x_start = c;

        i = i + 1;



    }

    cout << fixed << setprecision(5) << "RESULT " << c << endl << " Iterations: " << i << endl;

}
```

The root is at 17903534.23630

Does anyone know why my bisection method needs 55 iterations while Newton Raphson takes like 82?

Comment: Please get rid of that `goto`. You can replace it with a `do while` loop probably.

Comment: Also, where is the `main` function in the bisection program?

Comment: If you post incomplete code, no-one can reproduce your results with any certainty. The bisect variant isn't complete.

Comment: I thought it wasnt necessary since one can see the algorithm. But I will edit it!

Comment: When the tangent to the curve close to the root is near horizontal, NR method converges slowly. Otherwise, it's quick.

Comment: By splitting out `func1` and `funcderiv1` you are making 4-function calls per iteration. (which requires the setup of a function stack for every function call made). This won't impact the number of iterations, but will impact the timing. E.g. `((func1(x_start)) / (funcderiv1(x_start)))` and `abs(func1(x_start) / funcderiv1(x_start))`

Comment: Thanks for the quick answers. I know that NR converges more slowly if the tangent is near horizontal. But somehow my classmates get less iterations with NR than with bisection...
Have to edit here that we all enter the same error margin of 10E-7 btw

Comment: *Does anyone know why my bisection method needs 55 iterations while Newton Raphson takes like 82?* -- You could run your code in a debugger and set a breakpoint at the end/start of each iteration and inspect the variables.  In short, you have the answer, it's just that you should use the tools of the compiler suite to find the answer.

Comment: My debugger is buggy and doesnt work currently. Will try to fix it.

Comment: Print x, f(x) and f'(x) at each iteration, ask your classmates to do the same, and compare. If you have the same function and the same initial values, you should be printing the same numbers.

Comment: Also, you really should remove that `goto`.  Using `goto` to jump into the *middle* of a loop is one of the worst uses of it, even given the bad reputation it has.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie this would be a rather meaningless endeavour. The problem is in mathematics, not in programming.

Comment: According to Wolfram the expression for the derivative is incorrect.

Comment: @Evg Oh thats interesting. Let me check on that. (Actually double checked it before but lets see)

Comment: I now used the result of wolfram alpha for the derivative. Get the same root and still > 80 iterations.

Comment: Is there some reason you call both functions twice as many times as you need to in the NR version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the function

```
f(x) = A * (x - B) - C * (D / x - 1) / sqrt(x)

A = 0.00000000027
B = 10000000
C = 0.16460351745
D = 1000000000
```

the correct derivative is:

```
f'(x) = A - C (x - 3D) / (2 * x * x * sqrt(x))
```

Compare this with your expression:

```
g(x) = A - C (x - 3B) / (2 * x * x * sqrt(x))
```

After fixing the formula (by adding two zeros), your code makes 6 iterations:

```
RESULT 17903534.23630

 Iterations: 6
```

Comment: Whoopsie I made a boo boo